# Ember Data Edit After Create "Error: Attempted to handle event `didCommit` on <app@model: ...> while in state root.loaded.updated.uncommitted

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, race-condition, emberfire

*tl;dr:* Is editing a model's attributes while the model is saving officially unsupported? I seem to recall that attempts to edit while a record was inFlight used to be rejected by the state machine circa 2013, but I thought that limitation had been removed. It no longer throws a state-machine error...it just seems to cause errors later :/

---

In the app I'm working on, hitting enter creates a new entry and focuses the title field, letting the user immediately start typing. The changes to that field are automatically persisted with a debounced save. Generally this works well, but if I start typing too quickly, I'm getting the following error:

```
Attempted to handle event `didCommit` on <app@model: ...> while in state root.loaded.updated.uncommitted.
```

(I've included the full error & traceback at the bottom [1])

The record does appear to be properly persisted to the server ([Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) through the [EmberFire](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire) adapter), but there is other weirdness with the app from that point on (presumably because that iteration of the run loop blows up before completing).

To see what's up, I've attached observers onto the model's `currentState.stateName` and `title` fields. For a create-and-save without error, the record passes through the following states:

```
      [Press Enter; Pause]
               |
               V
 root.loaded.created.uncommitted
               |
               V
<title observer fires with blank>
               |
               V
   root.loaded.created.inFlight
               |
               V
       root.loaded.saved
               |
               V
        [Type in title]
               |
               V
root.loaded.updated.uncommitted
               |
               V
<title observer fires with value>
               |
               V
  root.loaded.updated.inFlight
               |
               V
       root.loaded.saved
```

When the error appears, the process looks like this:

```
 [Press Enter & type immediately]
               |
               V
 root.loaded.created.uncommitted
               |
               V
<title observer fires with blank>
               |
               V
   root.loaded.created.inFlight
               |
               V
[title observer fires with value]
               |
               V
       root.loaded.saved
               |
               V
root.loaded.updated.uncommitted
               |
               V
        <Error appears>
               |
               V
  root.loaded.updated.inFlight
               |
               V
       root.loaded.saved
```

My initial thought was that the error was being caused by the second save starting before the initial creation is complete, but the error happens in `root.loaded.updated.uncommitted` -- *before* the record enters `root.loaded.updated.inFlight`. I'm pretty sure this means the problem is caused by the actual editing of the field, not the call to `save()` the record.

Edit: Indeed, completely removing the saving of the title doesn't appear to have any effect. That seems to indicate the problem really does stem just from editing the field.

Looking at the traceback (below), it isn't obvious what is causing the `didCommit` event. I was wondering if my problem is the fault of EmberFire for calling `didSaveRecord()` while the model is in the wrong state, but [searching the EmberFire codebase doesn't turn up any calls to `didSaveRecord()` whatsoever](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=didSaveRecord&type=Code) so that doesn't appear to be the issue.

Is this just the as-designed behavior of Ember Data? If so, it seems like a pretty serious limitation that I haven't seen mentioned anywhere.[2]

[At one point, ED used to prevent setting properties while a record was inflight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134256/ember-suggestions-welcome-for-handling-inflight-errors), but I thought that limitation had been removed (and it isn't explicitly preventing me from doing so like it used to).

The first workaround that comes to mind is to buffer writes to the field until the model is in a "writable" state...except I've never seen any of the official Ember examples do that.

Is that the correct (or at least a reasonable) solution?

If so, what constitutes a "writable" state? Anything other than `inFlight`? (which I can just check for with the `isSaving` flag, right?)

And if not, is there another officially-recommended pattern to deal with this?

**Edit:**

In reading through [an old thread about autosave](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/autosave-patterns/1091) I came across [an article that mentions a *Buffered Proxy* pattern](https://teamgaslight.com/blog/an-autosave-pattern-for-ember-and-ember-data) (last main section: "Give Our Attributes a Buffer") that sounds pretty similar to what I'm describing. That links to [sample code by Luke Melia from 2013](https://gist.github.com/lukemelia/5632776) that [Stefan Penner said they used "regularly" (at that time).](https://gist.github.com/lukemelia/5632776#gistcomment-972859) Both of those two are active contributors to the Ember community, so I'd take taht as effectively "official" advice, but the question remains: is this still the suggested approach three years later?

**Edit:**

That proxy pattern is now packaged as [the ember-buffered-proxy Ember CLI addon](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-buffered-proxy), but it's README still doesn't really mention when this pattern might be needed (which seems to imply it's something occasionally useful in particular scenarios needing that functionality, not as a fix for a core limitation of Ember Data)

---

**[1]** Full error/traceback:

```
ember.debug.js:31352 Error: Attempted to handle event `didCommit` on <app@model:task::ember965:-KLmwiGUhqrUW_CiRGb4> while in state root.loaded.updated.uncommitted. 
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://app.localtest.me:4200/assets/vendor.js:25781:21)
    at InternalModel._unhandledEvent (http://app.localtest.me:4200/assets/vendor.js:82039:13)
    at InternalModel.send (http://app.localtest.me:4200/assets/vendor.js:81917:14)
    at InternalModel.adapterDidCommit (http://app.localtest.me:4200/assets/vendor.js:82220:12)
    at didSaveRecord (http://app.localtest.me:4200/assets/vendor.js:89092:21)
    at http://app.localtest.me:4200/assets/vendor.js:89814:15
    at Object.Backburner.run (http://app.localtest.me:4200/assets/vendor.js:10788:25)
    at _adapterRun (http://app.localtest.me:4200/assets/vendor.js:89648:31)
    at http://app.localtest.me:4200/assets/vendor.js:89805:13
onerrorDefault  @   ember.debug.js:31352
exports.default.trigger @   ember.debug.js:52095
(anonymous function)    @   ember.debug.js:53346
Queue.invoke    @   ember.debug.js:333
Queue.flush @   ember.debug.js:397
DeferredActionQueues.flush  @   ember.debug.js:205
Backburner.end  @   ember.debug.js:560
(anonymous function)    @   ember.debug.js:1126
```

**[2]** The only <strike>two</strike> <strike>three</strike> four mentions of similar issues that I've come across are:

1. [A case of issuing a second save request while the first is still in progress.](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/30699373-reproducible-invalid-transitions-when-saving-a-model-twice) In that case, the issue was solved by debouncing the save, but I'm already doing that, as well as re-queuing the save if a model save is already in progress (by explicitly checking the `isSaving` property). And, as I said earlier, even getting rid of the post-title-change autosave altogether doesn't seem to have an effect.
2. [A case of mutating data within a `DS.Transform`'s `serialize()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697991/ember-js-error-while-parsing-data-in-transformer-handeling-event-didcommit-in)
3. [An older case that looks like it could be the same problem, but is in a `Route`'s `model()` hook, where it is simple to wait for the save to complete before continuing.](https://github.com/locks/ember-localstorage-adapter/issues/95)
4. [Another older example of setting properties while `inFlight` causing an invalid state transition.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134256/ember-suggestions-welcome-for-handling-inflight-errors) First, this doesn't cause the same error anymore. Second, the only solution provided was to switch to [Ember Persistence Foundation](http://epf.io/), which appears to have been [abandoned in mid 2014](https://github.com/getoutreach/epf/commits/master) (Edit: [confirmed](https://github.com/getoutreach/epf/issues/149))

Comment: Are you getting any errors from Firebase? It's possible due to the number of requests that are being sent, that one request is failing, which sets the model state back to uncommitted. Then another request is coming back as a success, and the adapter tries to invoke didCommit on the state, which fails because it's an invalid transition for an uncommitted model.

Comment: @Vadim I'm not seeing any errors coming directly from EmberFire, though I guess it's possible they are somehow being hoovered before surfacing. Not sure of the best way to directly investigate if Firebase is returning errors, but it seems pretty unlikely that excessive load is causing my problem: even if I disable autosave, I'm able to fairly reliably trigger the error by just issuing a single create request, and then immediately editing the model field on the client.

Comment: That being said, it isn't clear to me what *is* causing the record to transition into the `root.loaded.updated.uncommitted` state: if a `becomeDirty` event is fired while still in `inFlight` it [looks like it should just stay in `inFlight`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.6.1/addon/-private/system/model/states.js#L291), and then transition to `root.loaded.saved` when `didCommit` fires. If the `becomeDirty` has already been handled, what is causing the transition from `saved` to `uncommitted`?

Comment: Ah, I see: when the record [enters the `saved` state, it checks if there are changed attributes](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.6.1/addon/-private/system/model/states.js#L551) and calls [`adapterDidDirty()`, which re-sends the `becameDirty` event](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/3a38988bcb694ed5ca46f68214e9876417b17bda/addon/-private/system/model/internal-model.js#L362), causing the `saved` state to [transition the record into the `updated.uncommitted` state](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.6.1/addon/-private/system/model/states.js#L562)

Comment: But that would mean there are two `didCommit()` events being fired: one received in `inFlight`, causing the transition to `saved`; one received in `uncommitted`, causing the error. Does that seem plausible/correct?

Comment: Yeah that was going to my other thought. That you probably have 2 requests being sent before the 1st one finishes. It looks like scanning the code that it just queues up pending saves rather than debouncing them. What are your debounce settings? It could be too short.

Comment: I'm using Ember.run.debounce with a 1000ms wait on changes to the title field. But I don't think that is the issue: the error still appears even if I completely remove the save code from the title observer. Just creating (and saving) the record and then immediately changing the field triggers the error, even without saving it again.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the source of the second `didCommit()`. The first `didCommit()` arrives while the (now dirty) record is `inFlight`. The [`didCommit()` handler](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.6.1/addon/-private/system/model/states.js#L300), transitions to `saved`, which notices the record is dirty and transitions to `updated.uncommitted`. The `inFlight` `didCommit()` handler then calls [invokeLifecycleCallbacks(), which triggers the second `didCommit()`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.6.1/addon/-private/system/model/states.js#L741) causing the error. Does this sound right?